# How to use environment variables in a .service script

Tags: linux, bash, elixir, systemd

I have an elixir project on a linux server. I have created a `.service` script which will start and stop the application with the following commands

```
systemctl start "my_app".service
systemctl stop "my_app".service
```

The `.service` file looks something like this...

```
[Unit]
Description="example app_name daemon"

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Restart=on-failure
Environment=MIX_ENV=prod "PORT=4000"

WorkingDirectory="the file path to my app"

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mix phoenix.server

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It works as expected, the one exception being that it will not read the environment variables. I can give the application access to them by adding them to the script manually like I have with `PORT=4000` above.

I want to know if there is a way for the `.service` file to access the env vars that I have on my server so I do not have to write them in each I use this script on a new server. Thanks in advance

Feel free to check out [the repo](https://github.com/healthlocker/healthlocker) if you would like more info on the project!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `EnvironmentFile=` directive in `[Service]` section.

```
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/some/textFile
```

Read [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what iamauser said, which is probably the answer you're looking for, there's another way to modify environment variables of services before they're launched. You can use [systemctl's environment commands](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#Environment%20Commands). Note that this will affect systemd's environment itself and all future services it launches. There are more bad reasons to use this than there are good, so avoid using this if iamauser's solution is sufficient.